# Error while updating property 'on' of a view managed by: AndroidSwitch

Tags: android, react-native

When I first time to run react native app an error occurs.

I really don’t how to resolve it because I’m a react-native freshman.

Error while updating property 'on' of a view managed by: AndroidSwitch:

[image: 1]

### That’s all info, thanks.

And the running npm package window print the log:

> You or one of the Babel plugins you are using are using Flow declarations as bindings.
>           Support for this will be removed in version 7. To find out the caller, grep for this
>           message and change it to a `console.trace()`.

Comment: Please add the error as text instead of a screenshot. A screenshot is hard to read and impossible to find in Google.

Comment: npm package window console log: Bundling `index.android.js`
  Transforming modules  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  44.1% (583/1029)...
        You or one of the Babel plugins you are using are using Flow declarations as bindings.
        Support for this will be removed in version 7. To find out the caller, grep for this
        message and change it to a `console.trace()`.

Comment: @JamesJones: I’ve appended the log, that’s all.

Comment: You should edit your question with additional detail, don't place it in a comment. This makes it easier for people to follow your question.

Comment: @JamesJones: Got it! Thank you for your advice. This is my first time to ask question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

`value` should be set like this:

```
value={false}
```

or

```
value={true}
```

You most probably have set it with the **wrong** syntax, like this

```
value="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my project, so I looked in the documentation of react native and found the solution.

You should use:

```
onValueChange
```

to solve the problem.

If you only use:

```
onChange
```

the error will occur

below is an example:

```
<CheckBox
  value={checked}
  onValueChange={setChecked}
/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, because i was passing string on value. You need to pass boolean.
For Example:

```
<CheckBox
  value={true} // true/false
  onValueChange={setChecked}
/>
```